# Tao Exercise 3.3.4 on Cancellation Laws for Function Composition

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Terence Tao's Analysis I 4ed Edition has an exercise 3.3.4

**Part 1:**

> In this section we give some cancellation laws for composition. Let
> $f: X \to Y$, $\tilde{f}: X \to Y$, $g : Y \to Z$, and
> $\tilde{g}: Y \to Z$ be functions. Show that if $g \circ f = g\circ \tilde{f}$
> and $g$ is injective, then $f = \tilde{f}$. Is the
> same statement true if $g$ is not injective?

**Part 2:**

> Show that if $g \circ f = \tilde{g} \circ f$ and $f$ is surjective, then $g = \tilde{g}$. Is the
> same statement true if f is not surjective?

**Question:** I am asking this question because I have checked against three different solution sources ([1](https://github.com/frederic-santos/taoanalysissolutions)), ([2](https://math.solverer.com/library/terence_tao/analysis_i/exercise_3-3-3)), ([3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541518/proof-of-function-cancellation-laws)), and my brain is disagreeing with them. So my request is for an explanation of where I am going wrong (or confirmation I am right).

I have noted down the specific arguments marked **thoughts** which I feel justify my solution in contrast with others.

---

**My Solution for Part 1**

We are given

$$g \circ f = g \circ \tilde{f}$$

and $g$ is injective.

If $g$ is injective, then by Definition 3.3.17, $g(x)=g(x') \implies x=x'$ for $x, x' \in X$, which here means

$$g(f(x))=g(\tilde{f}(x)) \implies f(x)= \tilde{f}(x)$$

That is, $f(x)$ and $\tilde{f}(x)$ map $x \in X$ to the very same values, and are thus, equal functions.

We have shown that if $g \circ f = g \circ \tilde{f}$ and $g$ is injective, then $f = \tilde{f}$. $\square$

If $g$ is not injective, then the statement is not necessarily false. That $f = \tilde{f}$ could be true for other reasons.

**Thought:** Consider $g(y)=1$ which is not injective. Then we can have $f(x)=x$ and $\tilde{f}(x)=x$, but still have $g(f(x)) = g(\tilde{f}(x))$. This demonstrates that $g$ not injective doesn't prevent $f = \tilde{f}$.

---

**My Solution to Part 2**

We are given

$$g \circ f = \tilde{g} \circ f$$

and $f$ is surjective.

If $f$ is surjective, then by Definition 3.3.20, every value of $y=f(x) \in Y$ has an $x \in X$.

If we consider

$$g(y) = \tilde{g}(y)$$

Then we conclude $g=\tilde{g}$. $\square$.

The conclusion didn't require $f$ to be surjective, so the statement is still true even if $f$ is not surjective.

**Thought:** If $f$ is not surjective, all it means is that $g(y)$ can't operate on the full domain $Y$, which doesn't prevent $g=\tilde{g}$.

Comment: For the second part of each Part, you want to give a counterexample showing that the statement is false.

Comment: On the second part about subjectivity, my conclusion is that $f$ is not required to be surjective. Am I in error?

Comment: Try constructing a counterexample where $Y=\{1,2\}$, $f$ is not surjective, $g\circ f = \tilde g\circ f$, but $g\neq \tilde g$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second part of each question, the question is asking whether the statement is true in *all* cases without the additional assumption. You just gave an example where it is true, but that is not what the question is asking.  This is just like the first part of each question - you gave a proof showing that it is true in all cases.

In the surjective case, you said:

> all it means is that $g$ can't operate on the full domain $Y$

but the problem says $g:Y \to Z$ which by definition means that $g$ must be defined on all of $Y$.

Comment: thanks for the comment, it is helpful. On thinking further, I can see how the statement abut injection is not *always* true, and that all we need is a counter-example to prove this - eg consider $f(x)=x$, $\tilde{f}=-x$, and $g(x)=x^2$. Here $g \circ f = g \circ \tilde{f}$ but $f \neq \tilde{f}$.

Comment: however, for the statement about surjection, my conclusion is that $f$ isn't required to be surjective. Others' solutions says it is required to be surjective. So I appear to have nothing to prove, unless my conclusion is wrong.

Comment: You said "all it means is that $g$ can't operate on the full domain $Y$" but the problem says $g : Y \to Z$ which by definition means that $g$ *must* be defined on all of $Y$.

Comment: Thanks Ted - if you'd like to add this to the Answer, I'll mark it as complete.

Comment: Added to the answer.